# Python - Add a space every two commas in a string

Tags: python, python-re

I have a string of floating number separated by commas:

```
s: "23.4, 56.8, 23, 67.8, 67.8, 234.6, 68.9, 345.56"
```

I would like to remove the space after the comma between two numbers forming "pairs" while keeping the other spaces:

```
new_s: "23.4,56.8, 23,67.8, 67.8,234.6, 68.9,345.56"
```

Any idea how to do it using python?

I already tried to remove spaces and and use the expression:

```
import re
s = "23.4, 56.8, 23, 67.8, 67.8, 234.6, 68.9, 345.56"
s = s.replace(" ", "")
new_s = re.sub(r',([^,]*,[^,]*),', r',\1 ', s)
print(new_s)
```

but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `(,[^,]*,)` to match every other comma and the text in between, then replace with the full match followed by a space:

```
s = '23.4,56.8,23,67.8,67.8,234.6,68.9,345.56'
new_s = re.sub(r'(,[^,]*,)', r'\1 ', s)
```

Output: `'23.4,56.8, 23,67.8, 67.8,234.6, 68.9,345.56'`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ozqpSx/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code for your query.

```
txt = "23.4, 56.8, 23, 67.8, 67.8, 234.6, 68.9, 345.56"

thislist = txt.split(",")
i = 0
newtxt = ''
while i < len(thislist):
    print(thislist[i])
    if i%2 == 0:
        newtxt =newtxt + thislist[i].strip() + ','
    else:
        newtxt =newtxt+ thislist[i].strip() + ', '
    i = i + 1

print(newtxt)
```